# Issue with the startActivityForResult

Tags: android, string, android-intent, start-activity

I would like to start activity#2 from activity#1 and ask for a result to taken from #2 to #1.

I read instruction and guides and tutorial but nothing helps me.

in Activity #2 I have a final string (let's call it"finalstring").

in activity #1 I have a button that sends the user to a POPUP activity (#2) which brings back to activity #1 if the users clicks outside the POPUP area.

In a few words, there is no return button.

So far I tried the basic approach of

```
Intent Open1 = new Intent(Two.this, Popup1.class);
startActivityForResult(Open1, String.finalstring);
```

but it does not work.

I see I should put a IF condition in some cases or else, but none of them work. What should I do?

Comment: Ok, Which one is Activity 1 and Activity 2? `popup1` is Activity 1?

Comment: sorry, popup1 is#2 and two is #1

Comment: no version of `startActivityForResult` takes a `String` as second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you understand it wrongly,

Lets say in your Activity1 (popup1):

You are starting Activity2 (popup2) like,

```
Intent startActivity2 = new Intent(Popup1.this,  popup2.class);
startActivityForResult(startActivity2, 0); // 0 is our request_code
```

Now, you have to implement `onActivityResult()` method in Activity1 (popup1), which will catch your result from Activity2 (popup2).

like,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check request 
    if (requestCode == 0) {
       // Make sure the request was successful
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // Here is your final string
           String resultFromActivity2 = data.getStringExtra("result);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your Activity2 (popup2), where you are calling finish, write your string result in intent like,

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result","your_string_result"); // your_string_result should be change with string you want to pass
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Cheers user. I get error in activity1 ("getExtra" is highlighted in red.) and the following in Activity2
http://pastebin.com/bdk7T6QP

Comment: replace `getExtra()` with `getStringExtra()`, I updated in answer. And without able to see your image I assume it is  `String.finalstring` so, replace it with your string from activity2 which you want to pass.

Comment: last question. If I want in Activity#1 to use the string I obtained from Activity#2 in this way, do I have to refer to it as "0" or with the name of my string (e.g. "finalstring")?

Comment: therefore I can use the name of the String (e.g. "finalstring"), correct?

Comment: on this line, `returnIntent.putExtra("result","your_string_result");` instead of `"your_string_result"` you can use `finalstring` in Activity2, so when you got your result in Activity1 in method `onActivityResult` you can see value of  `finalstring` in `string resultFromActivity2` variable..